# Expected value of a product of uniform variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I have a random variable $z=\Pi_i^n x_i$ and I'm trying to find an *analytical* (or an accurate) expression for the expected value where $z>c$ where $c$ is some constant and $x_i\sim U[a,b]$ and iid (i.e. trying to find $\mathbb{E}[z>c]$).

For example, lets say for two variables, $\mathbb{E}[z=x_1x_2>2]$ when $x_i\sim U[0,2]$. This I can solve geometrically which is the "triangle" formed by the edges $y=2,x\in[1,2]; x=2, y\in[1,2];$ and the hyperbola $2/x$, where $x\in[1,2]$. The area of this "triangle" is $\int_1^2(2-2/x)dx=0.6137$ and the expected value is the area of the triangle divided by the area of the box $=\frac{0.6137}{4}=0.1537\rightarrow 15.4\%$.

Is there a way to compute this for $n$ variables? How do I "break" the expected value $\mathbb{E}[1(x_1x_2...x_n>c)]$ to computable parts? Without Monte-Carlo simulations.

Comment: Your two-variable case is wrong already: the region $x_1x_2>2$ is not a triangle, its boundary is the hyperbole $x_2 = 2/x_1$.

Comment: You are right! Wow, what a mistake :( , I'll fix that in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case $a=0$, $-\log(x_i) = -\log(b) + y_i$ where $y_i = -\log(x_i/b)$ is an exponential random variable of rate $1$.

As a result, $-\log(z) = -n\log(b) + g_n$ where $g_n = \sum y_i$ is a Gamma(n,1) random variable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution )

What you want is $P(z>c) = P(-\log(z)< -\log(c)) = P(g_n<n\log(b)-\log(c))$. You can now use the CDF of the gamma distribution, see the wikipedia page, which uses a special function called the incomplete gamma function.

On the other hand, you can use this rewriting into sums to get asymptotic results as $n\to\infty$ using the CLT. This approach would also work when $a>0$.

For exact results when $a>0$, I don't know.

Comment: Very nice, it took me a while to convince myself about every step, but that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!